# "Ecosystem" or "eco-system" to describe something non-biological?

Tags: orthography

If "ecosystem" (no hyphen) is defined as "a system formed by the interaction of a community of organisms within their environment," should "eco-system" (hyphenated) be used to describe a system formed by the interaction of a community of *non-biological* (say, electronic) elements within their environment? or does it matter?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecosystem#Etymology

Comment: Why would you think the hyphen changes the meaning in that way?

Comment: When an interesting doubt comes up, it helps to share the *how* *why* of it. OP should explain how the idea of hyphenating to redefine came up. As for the question itself, it's ***ecosystem*** in biology/ecology as well as in all other fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merriam-Webster defines *ecosystem* as:

> **ecosystem**, noun : an ecological community considered together with the *nonliving* factors of its environment as a unit

However, *ecosystem* has been co-opted in the press in the past few years to describe, for example, the interrelationship between [Apple's AppStore and its iDevices](http://macdailynews.com/2009/12/07/apples_itunes_ecosystem_the_gift_that_keeps_on_giving_for_apple/).

Consider [this article](http://www.businessweek.com/magazine/content/07_28/b4042059.htm) from Businessweek regarding Apple's larger ecosystem, or the matter-of-fact use of *ecosystem* in [this article](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/tag/ecosystem/) comparing the Android Market to the "more mature iTunes ecosystem."

So, to answer the first part of your question, *ecosystem* has come to be used in the sense of the interaction of things (iPods, iPhones, iUsers) within their environment (iTunes, the AppStore), biological or not.

To answer the second part of your question, [*ecosystem*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ecosystem) is not hyphenated, and hyphenating it would not create a new word with a different meaning.

Comment: +1 for "and hyphenating it would not create a new word with a different meaning."

Answer (score -1):

It would just be a **system**. The "eco" in "ecosystem" comes from *[ecology](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ecology)*, which is a branch of biology, so it would not be appropriate to use it to describe non-biological systems (unless you are describing a system of artificially intelligent machines, and highlighting how life-like they are and how closely they resemble real, living beings).

From the [freeonlinedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/system):

> **System**
>
> 1. A group of interacting, interrelated, or interdependent elements forming a complex whole.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. So you think that if I were to use it to describe AI machines I could use it sans hyphen?

Comment: The word is generally written [without a hyphen](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ecosystem%2C+eco-system&year_start=1900&year_end=2012&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: -1: Usage, evolution, more! See Gnawme below for current journalese. Also, the answer is unsure about the hyphen.