# Should a hyphen be used when constructing words using suffixes such as "-ly" and "-wise" when the resulting word isn't in the dictionary?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, suffixes

Should a hyphen be used when constructing words using suffixes such as *-ly* and *-wise* when the resulting word isn't in the dictionary? For example:

> money-wise
>   moneywise

Which one is better?

Comment: Which dictionary? ;) [moneywise](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moneywise), [money wise](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/money%20wise), [moneywise](http://www.wordnik.com/words/moneywise), [moneywise](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moneywise)

Comment: @Em1  My example may not be good.  But you get the idea.  The question is on the general issue not one the specific instances given above.

Comment: Okay, well I only *thought* it was Not Constructive - I didn't actually *closevote*. I think the question should make clear that it's asking about the general principle, rather than one specific word-pair (?!), and it's quite possibly a duplicate anyway, but I've posted *my* position as an answer.

Comment: I really can’t see why a productive affix would need a hyphen. You are not making a compound word — and even those don’t last very long.  You are deriving a new word using an affix. It doesn’t matter whether you’re unselfconsciously repapering your superannuated farmhouse in some neogothic theme. Those don’t deserve hyphens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is inherently "better". Take, for example, [crab-wise](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7JMOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA549&dq=%22crab%20wise%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rV_LULOQGOao0AXxooCQBA&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22crab%20wise%22&f=false), which appears thus in *A thesaurus of traditional English metaphors* (published only 20 years ago), despite the fact that most dictionaries discarded the hyphen long ago.

As a general principle I think it's better to avoid unnecessary hyphens, so I'd say if you see the unhyphenated version of anything in any credible dictionaries, just copy them.

---

I shan't feel [hard done by](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hard-done-by) if this question is closed as a duplicate of [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word), but I do think the specific issue of *"What if it's not in the dictionary?"* isn't really covered there.

Even more specifically, *"What if the dictionaries disagree?"* isn't covered. For example, most dictionaries hyphenate [hard done-by](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/feel-hard-done-by), but I'm not going to take issue with Collins in my first link (who didn't). In that particular case one would avoid collapsing it into *hard doneby* because it would be tricky for the average reader to recognise the component words.

---

EDIT: I can't believe *nobody* has yet voted to close this as a dup. But here's another candidate - my own [Can word-hyphenation ever be semantically significant?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54422/can-word-hyphenation-ever-be-semantically-significant).

What I find fascinating about that one is most votes support answers saying the hyphen *can be* significant. After thinking about it, I've decided it probably can't, really. If context doesn't already imply the relevant word associations, it's some kind of orthographic game, not real language.

Answer (score 1):

I concur with @Fumblefingers, but I wanted to add the point of view that hyphenation of two words in a wordsmithing way always draws attention to the writer. Removing the hyphenation may leave you prone to grammar hawks and quizzical second glances, but it keeps the focus on the words.

Comment: That's a very good point (again, not addressed in the "possible dup" question). I don't recall ever seeing *screenwise* for example (my browser spellchecker doesn't like that either! :), but I can easily imagine plausible meanings and contexts. Including the hyphen in a "nonce word pairing" is only really worth doing if it's somehow necessary for legibility. If it isn't, I guess you might include it to call attention to what you're doing, but arguably that puts the focus on the *writer*, not *what he's writing about*.