# Does the affix "-centric" always require a hyphen when attached to another word (e.g. customer-centric, woman-centric etc.)?

Tags: punctuation

I understand that compound adjectives usually require a hyphen when placed before a noun, but what about when a word like "customer-centric" is placed after the noun?

Specifically, I'm wondering if the sentences below are both correct.

1. This is a very customer-centric business.
2. How do we make our business more customer-centric?

Comment: Not necessarily. See *egocentric, xenocentric, ethnocentric* etc.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Ah, yes, that's true. What about in the two sentences above? Does customer-centric become a word in and of itself?

Comment: Google books may help in this case: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2019&content=customer+centric%2Ccustomercentric%2Ccustomer-centric&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccustomer%20centric%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccustomercentric%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccustomer%20-%20centric%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Also read [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/94389/365490) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-com-pound-words-be-writ-ten-as-one-word-with-hy-phens-or-with-spac)